# Question about Planes in three-space, linear algebra

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors

Consider the two intersecting lines r = <1, 0, −2> + t<2, 3, 0> and r = <1, 0, −2> + t<−1, 1, 3>.
Find the equation of the line that is perpendicular to both of these lines and passes through
their point of intersection.

Comment: Do you understand why the equations $r_1(s) = \langle 1, 0, −2\rangle + s\langle 2, 3, 0\rangle$ and $r_2(t) = \langle 1, 0, −2\rangle  + t\langle −1, 1, 3\rangle$ describe lines in $3$d space?  Can you find a vector that is parallel to the first line?  Can you find a vector that is parallel to the second line?  Can you find a vector perpendicular to both a vector parallel to $r_1$ AND a vector parallel to $r_2$?  And what does this question have to do with planes?

Answer (score 0):

The intersection is obviously $(1,0,-2)$, so you've got that. A vector perpendicular to two other vectors in three dimensions is given by the cross product,
$$ (2,3,0) \times (-1,1,3) = (9,-6,5). $$